# Linux how to debug OS freeze issue

Tags: linux, kernel-module, panic

I am working on a kernel module and a user-space application to test that module.

The problem is that during testing my system hangs/freeze.

I have placed lots of debug prints in the code.

The last message that is printed is just before linux [select](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl2_select.htm) call in my user-space application. Does select somehow freeze the system?

So, How can i debug that where is problem? whether the problem is on user-space application or kernel module?

Comment: You have an uninitialised variable in line 42.

Comment: How do you know? I don't see the code.

Comment: @wildplasser: which file you are talking about? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As n.m mentioned, your userspace program can't freeze Linux, so its an error in your kernel module. The best way to debug this is to [use a kernel debugger](http://lwn.net/Articles/90913/), and figure out what your module is doing wrong.

Common errors are uninitialized pointers that your module passes to the kernel or locking issues, so take a close look at those.

Answer (score 2):

A userspace program cannot, by definition, freeze Linux. There's a bug in the kernel.

Comment: yep. But the problem is how to debug that?

Comment: Well, if I were to debug a kernel I would seriously consider something like a [kernel debugger](http://kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/jwessel/kdb/index.html).